# Postman Post call to Spring Controller is always null

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, postman

I have made an application in Spring boot with a database of users. Now i am trying to make a restcall with postman into the controller to send information about an user and save it in the database. The first time the restcall saves a null object in the database (all information is null) instead of the data in the postman call, so i think the error is in the call between postman and the controller.

The entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "localhost", catalog = "")
public class UserEntity {
    private int userId;
    private int unitId;
    private String roleName;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
```

The controller:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addNewUser",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String saveNewUser(UserEntity user) {
        try {
            userService.saveNewUser(user);
            return "User has been saved";
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            return "Nullpointer: User has not been saved";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

The postman call:
[image]

The debugger when i send the postman call:

```
user = {UserEntity@8954} 
userId = 0
unitId = 0
roleName = null
firstName = null
lastName = null
```

The goal of this project is not to "just make it work" but to make it work in a clean, proper way. That's why i want to use an object to send information instead of putting it in the url parameters.

If anyone can help me out by pointing out what goes wrong, i would be very thankfull. Any tips on code improvement giving the snippers is also very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing it as an array which is wrong, pass it like an object.

also You are defining userId,unitId as `int` in pojo but sending as string in body so change that to `"userId":1,"unitId":1` . Pass it like below.

```
{
  "userId":1,
  "unitId":1,
  "roleName":"AAA",
  "firstName":"BBB",
  "lastName":"CCC"
}
```

and change `public String saveNewUser(UserEntity user)` to `public String saveNewUser(@RequestBody UserEntity user)` by adding @RequestBody.

**Update**

Adding to that, change your request content type to json
[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply!
I have changed the userId and unitId to integers by removing the quote and set the type to json in postman, but they remain null values in the debugger. Do you know what else is wrong with the restcall?

Comment: i suspect you are using your previous request only..use {
  "userId":1,
  "unitId":1,
  "roleName":"AAA",
  "firstName":"BBB",
  "lastName":"CCC"
} instead which is in my answer..you dont have to use "UserEntity" key.

Comment: I used the json you wrote and it still didn't work, but i found the last problem:
The controller method parameter required @RequestBody for the data to be stored.

Comment: oops..missed that..thanks...public String saveNewUser(@RequestBody UserEntity user)